# Flash CS5 Font Inconsistencies Across Windows/OSX

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, cross-platform

We have multiple people working on a single project (and often even a single FLA), everyone's using Flash CS5.5 but some users are running Windows whilst others OSX. I've noticed that some Fonts appear differently when moving a FLA from OSX to Windows or vice versa. In particular, the vertical gutter will often be larger on Windows and sometimes even the leading will be significantly increased.

Published SWFs appear fine across both systems, it's only when you edit an unpublished FLA in the IDE or re-publish it that you notice the difference. I'll also add that this doesn't occur across all fonts and as far as I'm aware, I've only noticed it on the OTF file type (the Helvetica Neue LT family is one such example). And of course, all users have installed the same version of the font.

The problem exists regardless of whether the TextField has been added to the editor or programatically. TLF TextFields don't appear to exhibit this problem, however, we already have an extensive library built up that utilises the old TextField class so migrating to TLF isn't preferable.

This is incredibly frustrating as files move back and forth frequently and it basically boils down to telling users of one OS to ignore the alignment issues because they won't exist when published from the other system. Does anyone have any theories as to why this could be happening or how to get around it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well same applies to CS3 and CS4 versions.. <notforholywars>That was the reason why I moved from Windows to Mac platform 4 years ago.</notforholywars>

Nothing really you can do. This is Adobe's famous "cross-platform development" in the flesh =(